# C# Deploy a setup file, and Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.Version=13.0.2000.0. Culture=neutral

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, report, installation

I deploy my system with using Add-->Setup project,
and then i successfully install the system on my another computer, and the database work fine, but when i try to load crystal form the error message:

**Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.Version=13.0.2000.0. Culture=neutral**

anyone can help me?

After search the problem on internet, i found that the crystal report engine needed to be install, so i downloaded and installed, but now the error become:

*

```
************* Exception Text **************
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportViewer.set_ShowCopyButton(Boolean)'.
   at ProjectOCJB.Payment.InitializeComponent()
   at ProjectOCJB.Payment..ctor()
   at ProjectOCJB.Form2.pictureBox2_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.586 (RTMLDR.030319-5800)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
ProjectOCJB
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Setup/ProjectOCJB.exe
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.2003 built by: RTMLDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.2001 built by: RTMLDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.2001 built by: RTMLDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Data
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Data/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 13.0.2000.0
    Win32 Version: 13.0.1.220
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms/13.0.2000.0__692fbea5521e1304/CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
    Assembly Version: 13.0.2000.0
    Win32 Version: 13.0.1.220
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine/13.0.2000.0__692fbea5521e1304/CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll
----------------------------------------
CrystalDecisions.Shared
    Assembly Version: 13.0.2000.0
    Win32 Version: 13.0.1.220
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/CrystalDecisions.Shared/13.0.2000.0__692fbea5521e1304/CrystalDecisions.Shared.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.
```

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal, Sorry, what is GAC?

Answer (score 0):

You must download redistributable package for crystal reports,
depending of version of visual studio

http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-35074

in before version you must add this in app.config

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />
</startup>
<startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
</startup>
```

Comment: my system work properly, but if installed on another PC, crystal report not working.